# In QGIS 3.6, where is the "Enable 3D renderer" vector layer property?

Tags: 3d-model

In QGIS 3.4 I could enable the 3D renderer for a vector layer (properties/3D view/enable 3D renderer).
I can't find this option in QGIS 3.6 anymore.
How can I activate this again for a vector layer?

Comment: I can still find it under layer properties > 3D View. You have to change from no symbol to single symbol. I think the enable option was removed and replaced with the drop down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a little bit confusion that the indication "Enable 3D renderer" has disappeared